# Show that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $14^n$ can be represented as a sum of three perfect squares.

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

Show that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $14^n$ can be represented as a sum of three perfect squares.

I checked $(\mod 7)$ and deduced that the three squares can be $1,4,2(\mod 7) $ or all divisible by $7$ and for $n \ge 2$ they must be all divisible by $4$. But I am stuck here.

Comment: Following Dirichlet, any number that is not of the form $4^m(8k+7)$ can be represented as a sum of three squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use induction.

Step 1:

When $n = 1$, we have $14 = 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2$

When $n = 2$, we have $14^2 = 12^2 + 6^2 + 4^2$

Step 2: Suppose the statment is right for all $1 \le k \le n$.

In particular, $\exists a, b, c > 0$ s.t. $14^{n-1} = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$

Then for $n + 1$,

$14^{n+1} = 14^{n-1+2} = 14^{n-1} \times 14^2 $

$= 14^2\times a^2 + 14^2\times b^2 + 14^2\times c^2$

$= (14 \times a)^2 + (14 \times b)^2 + (14 \times c)^2$

Finally we can say the statement is true.

Comment: This is not induction, because you jump from $14^{n-1}$ to $14^{n+1}$.

Comment: @AlexM: $14^{n+1}=14^{n-1}\cdot 14^2$ so the induction is correct because the hypothesis is valid for $14^k$ with $k=1,2,...,n-1,n$ (it is an admitted variation of the principle of induction) and $14^2$ is itself a square.

Answer (score 8):

When $n=2k$ is even you are done since $$14^n=\left(14^k\right)^2+0^2+0^2$$ and when $n=2k+1$ is odd we can write $$14^n=14^{2k}\cdot(9+4+1)=\left(3\cdot 14^{k}\right)^2+\left(2\cdot 14^{k}\right)^2+\left(14^{k}\right)^2.$$

Comment: If the zeros feel like cheating to someone they can use $14^2=12^2+6^2+4^2$ and then proceed as in the odd case.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that an integer is a sum of three squares if and only if the integer is not of the form $4^a(8b+7)$ so we show that all powers of $14$ are not of this form.

$$14^n=(2(8-1))^n=2^n(8-1)^n=2^n(8M\pm1)$$
If $n$ is even we have $$14^n=4^k(8M+1)$$
If $n$ is odd we have $$14^n=2\cdot4^k(8M-1)=4^k(8N-2)=4^k(8T+6)$$ In both cases, when $n$ is even and odd, we see that $14^n$ is not of the form $4^a(8b+7)$ hence it is sum of three squares.